# Using StringBuilder getting null as output

Tags: java, string, collections, stringbuilder

I am doing one coding question in which I try to decrypt the input string. The procedure for the decryption is:
from 0 to 9 it represent alphabets from a to i.
then 10# represent j, 11# represent k and so.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Julia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="10#21#12#91";
        Julia obj=new Julia();
        String result=obj.decrypt(s);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public String decrypt(String msg)
    {
        HashMap<String,Character> hs=new HashMap<>();
        hs.put("1",'a');
        hs.put("2",'b');
        hs.put("3",'c');
        hs.put("4",'d');
        hs.put("5",'e');
        hs.put("6",'f');
        hs.put("7",'g');
        hs.put("8",'h');
        hs.put("9",'i');
        hs.put("10",'j');
        hs.put("11",'k');
        hs.put("12",'l');
        hs.put("13",'m');
        hs.put("14",'n');
        hs.put("15",'o');
        hs.put("16",'p');
        hs.put("17",'q');
        hs.put("18",'r');
        hs.put("19",'s');
        hs.put("20",'t');
        hs.put("21",'u');
        hs.put("22",'v');
        hs.put("23",'w');
        hs.put("24",'x');
        hs.put("25",'y');
        hs.put("26",'x');
        StringBuilder n=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=msg.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {

            if(msg.charAt(i)=='#' && i>=2)
            {
                StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder().append(msg.charAt(i-2)).append(msg.charAt(i-1));
                System.out.println(s);
                n.append(hs.get(s));
                System.out.println(n);
                i=i-2;
            }
            else
            {
                n.append(hs.get(msg.charAt(i)));
            }

        }
        return n.toString();
    }
}
```

That is code I wrote. But the output I am getting is `nullnullnullnullnull`.
I think the issue is with `StringBuilder`. Can anyone help me with that and explain the concept? If someone has better solution please guide.

Comment: Please format your code and post an [MCVE]

Comment: Note: `hs.put("26",'x');` is probably wrong, should be `hs.put("26",'z');`?

Answer (score 4):

You should not use data (a map) when you could have used a simple formula.

My suggestion:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class Julia {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String s = "10#21#12#91";
        final String result = decrypt(s);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String decrypt(final String s) {
        final List<Integer> crypt = new ArrayList<>();
        final String[] groups = s.split("#");
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            final String group = groups[i];
            int j = 0;
            // Special case for last group
            if ((i == (groups.length - 1)) && !s.endsWith("#")) {
                j = group.length();
            }
            if (group.length() > 2) {
                j = group.length() - 2;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                crypt.add(Integer.valueOf(group.substring(k, k + 1)));
            }
            if (j < group.length()) {
                crypt.add(Integer.valueOf(group.substring(j, group.length())));
            }
        }
        final StringBuilder n = new StringBuilder(crypt.size());
        for (final Integer c : crypt) {
            final char d = (char) (('a' + c) - 1);
            n.append(d);
        }
        return n.toString();
    }
}
```

Please note that there are two mistakes in the question: The letter a is 1, not zero, and the value for 26 is z, not x. The latter error is typical when you use data where a formula would do.

Since you are learning, I would note that the decrypt methods - both my suggestion and yours - should be static since they do not use any fields, so the instantiation is not necessary.

Comment: Your output is mot correct.By using your solution output is jul>> ,but the actual output is julia.
Thanks for Guidance :)

Comment: No Johathan. The question is from 0 to 9 no # is there.eg:
a --> 1
b --> 2
i -->9
j -->10#
k -->11#
z-- >26#

Comment: your algorithm is perfect. i tested it.

Answer (score 3):

This is **Pattern Matching problem** which can be solved by **Regex**.

Your code has some bugs and those are already pointed out by others. I don't see any solution which looks better than a simple regex solution.

Below regex code will output '**julia**' for input '**10#21#12#91**'.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Julia {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s="10#21#12#91";

    Julia obj=new Julia();
    String result=obj.decrypt(s);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public String decrypt(String msg)
{
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((\\d\\d#)|(\\d))");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(msg);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (regexMatcher.find())
        regexMatcher.appendReplacement(result, getCharForNumber(Integer.parseInt(regexMatcher.group(1).replace("#",""))));
    return result.toString();
}

private String getCharForNumber(int i) {
    return i > 0 && i < 27 ? String.valueOf((char)(i + 96)) : null;
}
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`hs.get(s)` will always return `null`, since `s` is not a `String`.

Try `hs.get(s.toString())`

`hs.get(msg.charAt(i))` will also always return `null`, since you are passing a `char` to `get` instead of `String`.

There may also be logic problems in your code, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks  it is working :) can u suggest any other good solution other than that ??

Comment: @SahilArora use Integer keys instead of Strings or a simple formula.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized version of your code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cipher = "10#21#12#91";

        System.out.print(decrypt(cipher));

        //output : julia
    }

    static String decrypt(String cipher) {
        //split with # to obtain array of code in string array
        String[] cipher_char_codes = cipher.split("#");

        //create empty message
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        //loop for each code
        for (String code : cipher_char_codes) {

            //get index of character
            int index = Integer.parseInt(code);

            if (index > 26) {
                char[] pair = code.toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < pair.length; i++) {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt("" + code.charAt(i));
                    message.append((char) ('a' + ((x - 1) % 26)));
                }
            } else {
                //map index into 1 to 26
                //find ascii code and cast into char
                message.append((char) ('a' + ((index - 1) % 26)));
            }
        }
        return message.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: You output is not correct. By 91 it means 9--> 'i' and 1-->'a'. So by using this %26 it will give the wrong answer.

Comment: The algorithm is right only for specific inputs. When i try "ajulia" (110#21#12#91) it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is indeed the way to go, and the code proposed by Pirate_Jack can be improved. It calls the expensive regex two superfluous times (replace is a regex operation).

Following is a yet improved version:

```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   public final class Julia3 {

       public static void main(final String[] args) {

           final String s = "10#21#12#91";

           final String result = decrypt(s);
           System.out.println(result);
       }

       public static String decrypt(final String msg) {
           final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((\\d\\d)(#)|(\\d))");
           final Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(msg);
           final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
           String c;
           while (regexMatcher.find()) {
               if (regexMatcher.group(2) == null) {
                   c = regexMatcher.group(1);
               } else {
                   c = regexMatcher.group(2);
               }
               result.append((char) ((Integer.parseInt(c) + 'a') - 1));
           }
           return result.toString();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not right :

```
hs.get(s)
```

s is a `StringBuilder`. It should be `hs.get(Char)`

**Edit:** an optional different solution:

```
    public class Julia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="10#21#12#91";

        List<String> numbers = splitToNumbers(s);

        Julia obj=new Julia();
        String result=obj.decrypt(numbers);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    /**
     *@param s
     *@return
     */
    private static List<String> splitToNumbers(String s) {

        //add check s is not null

        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        char delimiter = '#';
        List<String> numberAsStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        int charIndex = 0;

        while (charIndex < (chars.length -3)) {

            char theirdChar = chars[charIndex+2];
            if(theirdChar == delimiter) {

                numberAsStrings.add(""+chars[charIndex]+chars[charIndex+1]);
                charIndex +=3;

            }else {

                numberAsStrings.add(""+chars[charIndex]);
                charIndex ++;
            }
        }

        //add what's left
        while (charIndex < chars.length) {

            numberAsStrings.add(""+chars[charIndex]);
            charIndex++;
        }

        return numberAsStrings;
    }

    public String decrypt(List<String> numbersAsStings){

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        for (String number : numbersAsStings) {

            int num = Integer.valueOf(number);
            sb.append(intToChar(num-1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private char intToChar(int num) {

        if((num<0) || (num>25) ) {
            return '?' ;
        }
        return (char)('a' + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) can u suggest any other solution better then that ?

Comment: Yes, I added one.